# What to consider when calculating the number of subjects required for survival studies?

Tags: r, survival, sample-size

I was looking for formulas for calculating the number of subjects needed in survival analysis studies.
The formula that comes up most often is the one that takes the following parameters into account.

```
Median survival for control group
Median survival for treatment group
Accrual period
Additionnal follow-up time
Power
Significance level
Expected Hazard ratio
```

This elements are normally used to estimate the sample size required. However, in the real world, investigators cannot estimate recruitment time. Instead, they know their monthly /weekly recruitment capacity. So let's assume that after estimating recruitment time.
The number of recruitments per month* by the number of months < Calculated sample size. This remains a problem. Is there a formula that integrates this recruitment capacity by period? Is there an R package that does this?
How do we integrate lost to follow-up into the sample size calculation for survival analyses?
Should we just calculate the number of initial subjects and then add the percentage of those lost to follow-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit to power in survival analysis comes from the number of *events*, not the number of participants. The information that you show as requested for power analysis is needed to determine the expected number of observed events and their implications for power. In particular, additional follow-up time beyond initial accrual allows you to observe more events with the same number of enrolled participants

Real-world prospective survival studies, for example to evaluate a new drug, typically do have defined, planned accrual periods. You do that to convince yourself (and those funding the project) that your plan provides adequate power to detect the expected effect in a reasonable amount of time. If the power estimates are too low, then you have to find a way to get more patients per month or extend the accrual and/or follow-up times.

If you are working at a single site with known accrual per month, as the question suggests, you just try different accrual and follow-up times in the power-analysis software to estimate how long you need to run the study.

I find the `cpower()` function of the R [`Hmisc` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc), based on an assumption of exponentially distributed event times, to be useful for evaluating simple scenarios. If you use the R [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) (highly recommended for regression modeling of many types), it loads the `Hmisc` package.

The `Hmisc` package's `spower()` function allows incorporation of survival distributions other than exponential, and can include censoring in the calculations. The R [`simsurv` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=simsurv) allows for even more complicated scenarios.

Comment: Thank you @EdM for this explanation

Answer (score 1):

The accrual rate or period doesn't affect the required sample size or power of a study, it just affects at what point in time you'll actually be able to run the hypothesis test. If you expect you'll need 500 patients to run a well-powered test,  that's the required sample size, no matter how long it takes you to recruit them. The accrual rate just lets you estimate at what point you'll achieve that sample size. Seeing that you have recruited more or fewer patients than you expected doesn't indicate that you need to recruit more or less in the future, it just means you need to adjust your estimate of when you'll have sufficient data to run the desired test.

Think about it this way - say you've collected some body of survival data, with which you can run some hypothesis tests. Whether I tell you that data was collected ahead of schedule or behind schedule changes *nothing at all* about the power of the comparisons you can do with that data.

Comment: You are correct about analysis of data that are already collected, but this isn't exactly correct in the context of study planning. The number of _events_ limits the power of survival analysis, not the number of patients _per se_. Early-enrolled participants provide more observed events than later-enrolled participants; extending follow-up beyond the participant accrual period also increases the number of observed events. That makes the calculations a bit more complicated for study planning.